# Match name to ID and replace on insert

Tags: sql

Imagine an insert that looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO Inventory VALUES ('Product Name 1', 'Inventoried Location', Count),
('Product Name 2', 'Inventoried Location', Count),
('Product Name 3', 'Inventoried Location', Count),
...
('Product Name 1000', 'Inventoried Location', Count),
('Product Name 1001', 'Inventoried Location', Count)
```

Is there a way to match the Product Name to its ID in a Products table and substitute the ID for the name on insert? Needs to work for thousands of entries on the insert.

Comment: I think you're looking for UPDATE...WHERE

Comment: Looking for this: `INSERT INTO Inventory 
select prod_name_column, 'Inventoried Location', 5
from products`?

Comment: @juergend why not post this as an answer?

Comment: @Mureinik: Because I was not sure. And it looks like Siyual has the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance would be pretty awful on this, but if you're stuck with that particular format (say, from an Excel spreadsheet or something) you can write this as:

```
INSERT INTO Inventory VALUES 
(SELECT ProductID FROM Product WHERE ProductName = 'Product Name 1', 'Inventoried Location', 5),
(SELECT ProductID FROM Product WHERE ProductName = 'Product Name 2', 'Inventoried Location', 5),
(SELECT ProductID FROM Product WHERE ProductName = 'Product Name 3', 'Inventoried Location', 5),
...
(SELECT ProductID FROM Product WHERE ProductName = 'Product Name 1000', 'Inventoried Location', 5),
(SELECT ProductID FROM Product WHERE ProductName = 'Product Name 1001', 'Inventoried Location', 5)
```

Of course, this will break if you have multiple product entries with the same ProductName ...

If you want some better performance, you could insert the values into a temporary table, then do the lookup from that in a similar way to how Siyual suggested, e.g.,

```
INSERT INTO #tmpInventory (ProductName, ProductLocation, Number) VALUES 
('Product Name 1', 'Inventoried Location', 5),
('Product Name 2', 'Inventoried Location', 5),
('Product Name 3', 'Inventoried Location', 5),
.......

INSERT INTO INVENTORY (ProductID, ProductLocation, Number)
SELECT p.ProductID, t.ProductLocation, t.Number
FROM #tmpInventory t 
INNER JOIN Product p on t.ProductName = p.ProductName
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
Insert  Inventory
Select  ProductId, 'Inventoried Location', 5
From    Products 
Where   ProductName = 'Product Name'
```

Comment: If it were only a couple of entries I could do this. I should have clarified it would be for thousands of entries. Need something scalable.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but for ease of writing, you could make it into a `Stored Procedure` and call that instead?

Comment: I updated my original post to more closely reflect what I'm trying to do.